# Stop chrome from reloading a tab in loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension and one of the actions is to reload the current tab after changing the URL. This is the code below:

```
submitChoices.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  let url = fieldChoices(tab); // This returns the new Url based on some choices
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function () {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url });
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
      chrome.tabs.reload(); // Issue seems to be here
    });
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the chrome.tabs.reload(); seems to be stuck in a loop. The tab keeps on reloading and only stops after I change tabs or switch focus to another window/app.
Any tips?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, with many parts you don't need. It keeps reloading because the `onUpdated` listener starts again every time. But you don't need the listener at all, and you don't need the second `tabs.query` that you are not even using:

```
submitChoices.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    let url = fieldChoices(tab); // This returns the new Url based on some choices
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url });
});
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but it doesn't update the page.
I'm working with an internal tool for my company where I can insert the parameters via url. The Url gets updated this way, but the page itself doesn't show the results with the new parameters. So I need to reload the page.
About the second query, yeah, you were right. There was no need for that! Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen, but maybe try to add `chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);` after the `.update()`.